# Jasmine + Istanbul coverage not working

Tags: javascript, jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm working on lite javascript framework and my coverage statements can't reach up to 10% even though I'm sure when I'm doing my specs almost all of my functions are called.

If someone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong, I will be glad to hear it.

My project build: 
https://travis-ci.org/devoralive/doa

My project repository:
https://github.com/devoralive/doa

My specs with jasmine:
https://github.com/devoralive/doa/tree/master/specs/doa

And the sources:
https://github.com/devoralive/doa/tree/master/src/doa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve my problem in gaving name to my requirejs modules during a try to create a dist version.

Answer (score 0):

did you take a look at your HTML coverage report ?

Only 3 of 22 functions are tested, in regard of travis trace... you may have to test all possibles outputs, the HTML report is more helpful than LCOV report in this case.

Regards,

Comment: Yes I take a look on my HTML coverage report and all my function stay in red.

Comment: can you give me a way to test coverage outside travis ? I don't know well grunt.

Comment: I have update the README.md to explained how to install and test the project.